# Does socket.gettime function in Lua require Internet connection?

Tags: sockets, lua

I've understood that sockets use the Internet (to put it very simply).

I was wondering if using `socket.gettime` function requires Internet connection as well? I'm working on a game and I'm tracking time using `socket.gettime` instead of `os.time` for the improved accuracy.

Can I rest assured that my code will work even if the player doesn't have Internet connection or should I switch back to `os.time`?

Comment: pro-tip: next time disconnect your computer and call `socket.gettime()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sockets do not use the Internet.

Sockets represent communication end points. You can use them to communicate between processes on a system, in a local network or via the Internet.

You do not require Internet connection to use sockets.

socket.gettime just gives you the system time in seconds with 4 decimals.

http://underpop.online.fr/l/lua/luasocket/socket.html